# How to start talkd daemon?

Tags: terminal, tty, dmesg, xinetd, inetd

I'd like to set up a `talkd` deamon on my machine to talk with other users. The deamon should be set through inetd:

```
# /usr/sbin/in.talkd
must be run from inetd.
```

How do I configure `inetd` to start the `talk` daemon?

Answer (score 1):

/etc/inetd.conf

```
talk  dgram udp wait nobody.tty /usr/sbin/in.talkd in.talkd
```

Comment: Thanks. inetd service is started with `service openbsd-inetd start`